# Why is jQuery 1.6.x not an option?

Tags: javascript

All the other versions of jQuery are listed; version 1.6.x is missing.

What is the reasoning for not including 1.6.x in the jQuery Update module?

[image]

Comment: what about 2.0.x?

Comment: and also 1.12.x

Answer (score 2):

There are compatibility problems with jQuery 1.6.x & D7. If you'd like to know the details here's the [current outstanding feature request for it](https://www.drupal.org/node/1156860).

Comment: Yes, jQuery 1.6, in general, made lots of people cry when it came out.  That was a huge BC break.